# jQuery is not working on Chrome but works fine with Firefox

Tags: jquery

I wrote this code to show and hide a sidebar menu. It works fine with Firefox but when I use it on Chrome it shows and displays on button click on auto post back. Does someone have a suggestion on how to solve this?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#sidebar").hide();
    $("#Hide").hide();

    $("#Show").click(function () {
        $("#Show").hide();
        $("#Hide").show();
        $("#sidebar").fadeToggle("very slow", function () {});
    });

    $("#Hide").click(function () {
        $("#Hide").hide();
        $("#Show").show();
        $("#sidebar").fadeToggle("very slow", function () {});
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors in Chrome? The code you've provided appears to work fine for me in Chrome: https://jsfiddle.net/5wna2m1v/

Comment: What about chrome browser cache?!

Comment: i have check but it doesnt display any jquery......

Comment: Rory take another button and check on that click....

Comment: Whenever I click on another button in chrome it displays the sidebar and hide it in a moment.So why it is happening...??

Comment: For me the code also seems to work. Not sure what you want to achieve exactly.

Comment: Actually I have hidden the hide button and sidebar on page load and on show button it displays but whenever there is post back event it displays and hide in moment...this is the problem when i work with chrome...

Comment: There is an error that shows 2 messages are hidden by the filters...What does it mean..??

Comment: Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.
browserLink:37 Setting 'XMLHttpRequest.withCredentials' for synchronous requests is deprecated.

Comment: The above is the error on my chrome...